# Viability check for a project on Salesforce

Tags: force.com-sites, custom-object, webservices, knowledge, articles

I have this project in discussion, and I would like to see if this project can possibly be developed on top of Salesforce.

- I need to host **N** number of responsive web pages on Salesforce which should be publicly accessible. (Anyone with a link should be able to access the document)
- Also, through an API or by some other means, I need to retrieve metadata about these hosted webpages in JSON format. Meta data should typically include the actual URL of each webpages, and some other custom information about each of them.
- One end of this project will be **Android** and the other end will be Salesforce.
- And once these metadata is retrieved on the mobile side, I need to fetch the correct document using the URL from the metadata.
- The user can press **Yes** or **No** on the screen which displays the web page
- In either of the situations, I should be able to send this information back to Salesforce and store it there in some way. (Custom objects may be?)

Is this project viable on the Salesforce platform? If yes, can someone shed some light into the same? If not, what are the limitations of the Salesforce platform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To your points...

- *"host N number of responsive web pages on Salesforce which should be publicly accessible"*. The Salesforce Force.com 
  sites technology is aimed at providing this functionality, you can read more about it [here](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Force.com_Sites).
- *"retrieve metadata about these hosted webpages in JSON format"*. Salesforce provides a means to write your own [REST API using Apex](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_rest_code_sample_basic.htm), this can return JSON in any structure you want. Such as a list of your pages, which you could query for via SOQL over the [ApexPage](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/officetoolkit/Content/sforce_api_objects_apexpage.htm) object.
- *"I need to fetch the correct document using the URL from the metadata"*. You can make a standard HTTP GET call from your mobile app to download the pages or a [Document](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_document.htm) file marked as available externally.
- *"send this information back to Salesforce and store it there in some way"*. You could write an Apex REST API to receive the new document and update the Document object record. You cannot however update Visualforce pages, not sure if the pages need updating or the documents your wanting to expose here?

In summary, I'm confident you can build this with Force.com. You may also want to take a look at the excellent Salesforce mobile developer documentation and development kits [here](http://www2.developerforce.com/en/mobile/getting-started). Hope this helps!

Comment: I concur, I can't see anything in particular that would be difficult/impossible to implement on the platform.